# How to put divs in separate lines without occupying the entire width on each line?

Tags: html, css

I think it is possible to unset this element to not block space, but i don't know which CSS code to do that. Below is my code:

```css
.customLabel{
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black
}

.customLabel>div{
    background: #f0ad4e;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customLabel">
  <div class=''>hello</div>
  <div class=''>hi hi hi hi </div>
  <div class=''>god</div>
</div>
```

All I want want is like this image[image]

So if anyone can please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to display these elements next to each other? Sorry, but it's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float the divs to the right and add `clear:both`. You'll need to use a `clearfix` so that the floats are contained...here I used `overflow:hidden` on the parent wrapper.

```css
.customLabel {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.customLabel>div {
  background: #f0ad4e;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="customLabel">
  <div class=''>hello</div>
  <div class=''>hi hi hi hi</div>
  <div class=''>god</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display:inline-block` and add breaks `<br>` if you want to go next line:

```css
.customLabel{
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black
}

.customLabel>div{
    background: #f0ad4e;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.notblock{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div class="customLabel">
  <div class='notblock'>hello</div><br>
  <div class='notblock'>hi hi hi hi </div><br>
  <div class='notblock'>god</div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't adding a `<br>` considered a bad idea?

Comment: @PraveenPuglia Hm... worse than having floats and clears at the same time?

Comment: Yep. A `<br>` tag potentially introduces ghost gaps because of it's inline nature. Also, <br> tags have long led to layout breaks. Floats are more stable. It just requires you to pay attention when you should float and if you properly cleared that.

Comment: Thank you all. Floating the elements cause the parent to have height of 0px except the height is set manually. In this case as the parent div had border, I preferred using `<br>` to achieve the same output as question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. I am using the CSS Flexbox to accomplish this. It has real good browser support as of now so this shouldn't be a problem.

```css
.customLabel{
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.customLabel>div{
    background: #f0ad4e;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customLabel">
  <div class=''>hello</div>
  <div class=''>hi hi hi hi </div>
  <div class=''>god</div>
</div>
```

Read more about Flexbox here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/